# Can't return a vector of structs declared in header file

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I want my getFeatures function to return a vector of structs. The struct I have declared in the header file, but when in my .cpp file I try to write my function name I get a use of undeclared identifier error. The identifier is declared and I can use it in other functions. Also when I write my return statement I get a no viable conversion of vector type to int error. In my header file I have the function prototype and it states my function should return a vector of my struct type, not of type int. What on earth is going on?

```
#include "Feature_Builder.h"

Feature_Builder::Feature_Builder()
{
    int input;
    vector<int> intImageVals, temp;

    fstream file;

    file.open("Integral_Images.txt", ios::in);

    if (file.fail())
    {
        cerr << "File not open!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<12876; i++)
    {
        file >> input;
        while (input != -1)
        {
            intImageVals.push_back(input);

            file >> input;
        }

        buildFeatureOne(intImageVals);
        buildFeatureTwo(intImageVals);
        buildFeatureThree(intImageVals);
        buildFeatureFour(intImageVals);

        featureIndex = 0;
        intImageVals.clear();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************************
 This is the function with errors! XCode says featureValues is an undeclared
 identifier and that features should be of type int!
 *****************************************************************************/
vector<featureValues> Feature_Builder::getFeatures()
{
    return features;
}
```

And my header file

```
#ifndef Facial_Learner_Feature_Builder_h
#define Facial_Learner_Feature_Builder_h

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Feature_Builder
{
private:
    void buildFeatureOne(vector<int>);
    void buildFeatureTwo(vector<int>);
    void buildFeatureThree(vector<int>);
    void buildFeatureFour(vector<int>);

    struct featureValues
    {
    private:
        vector<int> vals;

    public:
        inline void pushValue(int value)
        {vals.push_back(value);}

        inline int getValue(int i)
        {return vals[i];}
    };

    int featureIndex;
    vector<featureValues> features;

public:
    Feature_Builder();
    vector<featureValues> getFeatures();
};

#endif
```

Comment: i would actually not return a vector that way... you should return a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the correct scoping for the inner structure:

```
vector<Feature_Builder::featureValues> Feature_Builder::getFeatures() { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. I had no clue you needed to specify the scope. Thanks!